# Why is my outcome different in second run that first

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops, variables

I'm running this code

```
sample_data = word_ratings_merged[:5]
#Create a copy
data_c = sample_data.copy()

#Now drop the values that aren't rated
for w_list in data_c.unique_words:
    word_list = w_list
    print(word_list)
    print(len(word_list))
    print("\n------------------------------------------------------\n")
    for word in word_list:
        if word in word_score_series_copy.keys():
            pass
        else:
            word_list.remove(word)
            print(word)
    print("\n-------------------------------------------------------\n")
    print(len(word_list))
    print("\n-------------------------------------------------------\n")
```

For the sake of this question;
word_ratings_merged is a df. One of the columns is unique_words, which contains a list of different words.
word_score_series_copy is a pandas series, that has words as the keys. The values don't matter here.

When I first run this loop, it outputs that some words have been removed, and the lists are now of different lengths at the start vs the end.
However, when I run it again, it shows the "shortened" list length and outputs that no words were removed.

Shouldn't the output be the same, since I establish `data_c` as fresh every time I run this?

Edit:
`word_ratings_merged`

```
Rating  unique_words
0   4   [advantage, advice, anniversary, arrived, aveda, bangs, bath, bed, check, clean, closing, comfortable, deal, did, disappointed, distance, doors, easy, evening, existent, expensive, experience, goldfish, good, got, great, hallway, having, hear, heard, high, hotel, just, late, like, little, location, longer, loud, maybe, morning, music, neck, neighbors, nice, night, noisy, non, not, opening, overall, parking, pay, people, pillows, previous, products, quick, reviews, room, shopping, size, soundproof, stay, staying, stiff, taken, talking, took, touch, valet, view, walking, woke]
1   2   [advertised, advertising, alley, anniversary, arrival, arrived, asked, asking, away, bags, bathroom, bedroom, beds, bellman, best, better, block, booked, bottle, breakfast, bring, building, business, busy, calls, celebrate, cell, chain, champagne, charge, chating, chocolate, clean, cleaner, clerk, comfortable, concerned, control, controls, convenient, copy, correct, couch, covered, day, decided, deliver, description, desk, diamond, did, directly, does, duty, ect, email, emailed, embassy, exist, extra, eyes, failure, false, foam, follow, free, furnished, gee, good, got, great, green, guess, guest, half, hard, heat, help, helpful, high, hilton, hood, hotel, hotels, hours, housekeeping, impressed, inch, indifferent, inform, inside, kidding, kimpton, know, late, left, light, like, mail, make, ...]
2   3   [accessories, amenities, arrange, arrival, asked, away, bath, bathroom, bed, before, big, blue, book, bottle, box, bright, broken, bubble, busy, called, calls, came, car, champagne, change, channel, check, checked, checkin, choice, chore, comfortable, comparison, concierge, cover, decided, degrees, desk, did, digital, disappointing, disorganized, dock, downside, driver, drop, easy, experience, face, facilities, far, felt, filled, fish, footage, forgot, forgotten, functioning, gesture, going, good, got, great, guidance, happen, happy, hard, hotel, housekeeping, huge, impression, ipod, jacuzi, jets, kept, large, larger, later, level, light, look, maintainence, malfunctioned, mediterranean, missed, monaco, morning, nap, nice, night, non, not, open, party, person, picked, pillowsattentive, play, positives, price, ...]
3   5   [animal, area, bathrobes, big, brandi, chain, closed, coffee, color, cosy, curtains, decor, did, downtown, eclectic, enjoyed, excellent, feature, feel, felt, free, friendly, goldfish, great, hair, hotel, internet, laptops, like, lobby, location, look, lovely, main, mix, monaco, named, nice, palatte, partake, pattens, personality, pet, print, pulled, rock, room, service, shopping, short, showed, signs, sleeping, smells, staff, stars, stay, sterile, striped, stroll, suite, tea, thought, time, touch, unique, wine, wireless, wonderful, worked]
4   5   [accept, activities, answer, apologized, arabic, area, ass, available, away, awesome, barely, bathroom, bernard, besite, best, better, blocks, booked, bucks, buddy, building, cab, called, cell, charge, check, christmas, city, coffee, comments, company, complain, contains, deals, desk, did, dog, doing, doorman, downfall, dressed, driver, english, entrances, evening, face, fact, family, floor, foyer, funny, game, getting, girlfriend, going, good, got, great, greatest, head, hear, helpful, hit, homeless, hotel, hotels, house, huge, humpin, issue, jetted, just, keeping, knock, language, large, laughing, leave, lights, located, making, mantained, miles, mind, not, offered, online, package, parking, pay, phone, pike, place, plan, police, presence, price, priceless, problem, promply, ...]
```

Also here's my output the first time I run it:

```
['advantage', 'advice', 'anniversary', 'arrived', 'aveda', 'bangs', 'bath', 'bed', 'check', 'clean', 'closing', 'comfortable', 'deal', 'did', 'disappointed', 'distance', 'doors', 'easy', 'evening', 'existent', 'expensive', 'experience', 'goldfish', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'hallway', 'having', 'hear', 'heard', 'high', 'hotel', 'just', 'late', 'like', 'little', 'location', 'longer', 'loud', 'maybe', 'morning', 'music', 'neck', 'neighbors', 'nice', 'night', 'noisy', 'non', 'not', 'opening', 'overall', 'parking', 'pay', 'people', 'pillows', 'previous', 'products', 'quick', 'reviews', 'room', 'shopping', 'size', 'soundproof', 'stay', 'staying', 'stiff', 'taken', 'talking', 'took', 'touch', 'valet', 'view', 'walking', 'woke']
74

------------------------------------------------------

bangs
goldfish
neck
soundproof
stiff

-------------------------------------------------------

69

-------------------------------------------------------

['advertised', 'advertising', 'alley', 'anniversary', 'arrival', 'arrived', 'asked', 'asking', 'away', 'bags', 'bathroom', 'bedroom', 'beds', 'bellman', 'best', 'better', 'block', 'booked', 'bottle', 'breakfast', 'bring', 'building', 'business', 'busy', 'calls', 'celebrate', 'cell', 'chain', 'champagne', 'charge', 'chating', 'chocolate', 'clean', 'cleaner', 'clerk', 'comfortable', 'concerned', 'control', 'controls', 'convenient', 'copy', 'correct', 'couch', 'covered', 'day', 'decided', 'deliver', 'description', 'desk', 'diamond', 'did', 'directly', 'does', 'duty', 'ect', 'email', 'emailed', 'embassy', 'exist', 'extra', 'eyes', 'failure', 'false', 'foam', 'follow', 'free', 'furnished', 'gee', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'green', 'guess', 'guest', 'half', 'hard', 'heat', 'help', 'helpful', 'high', 'hilton', 'hood', 'hotel', 'hotels', 'hours', 'housekeeping', 'impressed', 'inch', 'indifferent', 'inform', 'inside', 'kidding', 'kimpton', 'know', 'late', 'left', 'light', 'like', 'mail', 'make', 'manager', 'member', 'mixed', 'morning', 'needed', 'neighborhood', 'nice', 'night', 'not', 'nothing', 'offer', 'paid', 'phone', 'picky', 'pillows', 'preferred', 'printed', 'printout', 'prior', 'property', 'provide', 'ranged', 'rates', 'really', 'reply', 'reservation', 'rise', 'room', 'run', 'said', 'saying', 'screen', 'seattle', 'send', 'sensitive', 'shine', 'shopping', 'short', 'shot', 'showed', 'sitting', 'solution', 'sorry', 'special', 'spots', 'staff', 'standard', 'start', 'stay', 'strawberries', 'suite', 'suites', 'suits', 'super', 'sure', 'survey', 'tape', 'tell', 'the', 'things', 'this', 'told', 'took', 'trip', 'trips', 'unlike', 'view', 'wanted', 'website']
169

------------------------------------------------------

advertising
chating
controls
ect
exist
failure
foam
gee
hood
inform
kidding
printout
ranged
reply
shine
solution
survey

-------------------------------------------------------

152

-------------------------------------------------------

['accessories', 'amenities', 'arrange', 'arrival', 'asked', 'away', 'bath', 'bathroom', 'bed', 'before', 'big', 'blue', 'book', 'bottle', 'box', 'bright', 'broken', 'bubble', 'busy', 'called', 'calls', 'came', 'car', 'champagne', 'change', 'channel', 'check', 'checked', 'checkin', 'choice', 'chore', 'comfortable', 'comparison', 'concierge', 'cover', 'decided', 'degrees', 'desk', 'did', 'digital', 'disappointing', 'disorganized', 'dock', 'downside', 'driver', 'drop', 'easy', 'experience', 'face', 'facilities', 'far', 'felt', 'filled', 'fish', 'footage', 'forgot', 'forgotten', 'functioning', 'gesture', 'going', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'guidance', 'happen', 'happy', 'hard', 'hotel', 'housekeeping', 'huge', 'impression', 'ipod', 'jacuzi', 'jets', 'kept', 'large', 'larger', 'later', 'level', 'light', 'look', 'maintainence', 'malfunctioned', 'mediterranean', 'missed', 'monaco', 'morning', 'nap', 'nice', 'night', 'non', 'not', 'open', 'party', 'person', 'picked', 'pillowsattentive', 'play', 'positives', 'price', 'provide', 'reasonable', 'relax', 'requests', 'rest', 'room', 'rooms', 'said', 'salts', 'seattle', 'separate', 'service', 'settings', 'shower', 'soaking', 'sold', 'sound', 'space', 'special', 'spent', 'square', 'staffnegatives', 'stay', 'suite', 'surprised', 'the', 'thermostat', 'tip', 'told', 'touch', 'try', 'tub', 'unit', 'use', 'voucher', 'waiting', 'wakeup', 'warm', 'water', 'way', 'weekend', 'whirlpool', 'work', 'yep']
144

------------------------------------------------------

accessories
before
bubble
chore
digital
disorganized
footage
functioning
guidance
jacuzi
maintainence
monaco
pillowsattentive
salts
settings
staffnegatives
thermostat
wakeup
whirlpool
yep

-------------------------------------------------------

124

-------------------------------------------------------

['animal', 'area', 'bathrobes', 'big', 'brandi', 'chain', 'closed', 'coffee', 'color', 'cosy', 'curtains', 'decor', 'did', 'downtown', 'eclectic', 'enjoyed', 'excellent', 'feature', 'feel', 'felt', 'free', 'friendly', 'goldfish', 'great', 'hair', 'hotel', 'internet', 'laptops', 'like', 'lobby', 'location', 'look', 'lovely', 'main', 'mix', 'monaco', 'named', 'nice', 'palatte', 'partake', 'pattens', 'personality', 'pet', 'print', 'pulled', 'rock', 'room', 'service', 'shopping', 'short', 'showed', 'signs', 'sleeping', 'smells', 'staff', 'stars', 'stay', 'sterile', 'striped', 'stroll', 'suite', 'tea', 'thought', 'time', 'touch', 'unique', 'wine', 'wireless', 'wonderful', 'worked']
70

------------------------------------------------------

animal
brandi
eclectic
goldfish
laptops
monaco
palatte
pattens
pet
sterile

-------------------------------------------------------

60

-------------------------------------------------------

['accept', 'activities', 'answer', 'apologized', 'arabic', 'area', 'ass', 'available', 'away', 'awesome', 'barely', 'bathroom', 'bernard', 'besite', 'best', 'better', 'blocks', 'booked', 'bucks', 'buddy', 'building', 'cab', 'called', 'cell', 'charge', 'check', 'christmas', 'city', 'coffee', 'comments', 'company', 'complain', 'contains', 'deals', 'desk', 'did', 'dog', 'doing', 'doorman', 'downfall', 'dressed', 'driver', 'english', 'entrances', 'evening', 'face', 'fact', 'family', 'floor', 'foyer', 'funny', 'game', 'getting', 'girlfriend', 'going', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'greatest', 'head', 'hear', 'helpful', 'hit', 'homeless', 'hotel', 'hotels', 'house', 'huge', 'humpin', 'issue', 'jetted', 'just', 'keeping', 'knock', 'language', 'large', 'laughing', 'leave', 'lights', 'located', 'making', 'mantained', 'miles', 'mind', 'not', 'offered', 'online', 'package', 'parking', 'pay', 'phone', 'pike', 'place', 'plan', 'police', 'presence', 'price', 'priceless', 'problem', 'promply', 'realize', 'recommend', 'return', 'right', 'room', 'safes', 'said', 'screamed', 'screams', 'seahawk', 'second', 'service', 'shops', 'spanish', 'speak', 'spoke', 'stadium', 'staff', 'started', 'stay', 'stowed', 'street', 'taking', 'talking', 'tasting', 'taxi', 'tell', 'thing', 'time', 'told', 'took', 'travel', 'tub', 'turn', 'view', 'voucher', 'vouchers', 'walk', 'walked', 'want', 'waterfront', 'way', 'website', 'websites', 'went', 'wine', 'wonderful', 'worked']
148

------------------------------------------------------

arabic
ass
bernard
buddy
contains
downfall
entrances
humpin
jetted
laughing
mantained
presence
priceless
promply
safes
screamed
seahawk
stowed

-------------------------------------------------------

130

-------------------------------------------------------
```

And then the second run:

```
['advantage', 'advice', 'anniversary', 'arrived', 'aveda', 'bath', 'bed', 'check', 'clean', 'closing', 'comfortable', 'deal', 'did', 'disappointed', 'distance', 'doors', 'easy', 'evening', 'existent', 'expensive', 'experience', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'hallway', 'having', 'hear', 'heard', 'high', 'hotel', 'just', 'late', 'like', 'little', 'location', 'longer', 'loud', 'maybe', 'morning', 'music', 'neighbors', 'nice', 'night', 'noisy', 'non', 'not', 'opening', 'overall', 'parking', 'pay', 'people', 'pillows', 'previous', 'products', 'quick', 'reviews', 'room', 'shopping', 'size', 'stay', 'staying', 'taken', 'talking', 'took', 'touch', 'valet', 'view', 'walking', 'woke']
69

------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------

69

-------------------------------------------------------

['advertised', 'alley', 'anniversary', 'arrival', 'arrived', 'asked', 'asking', 'away', 'bags', 'bathroom', 'bedroom', 'beds', 'bellman', 'best', 'better', 'block', 'booked', 'bottle', 'breakfast', 'bring', 'building', 'business', 'busy', 'calls', 'celebrate', 'cell', 'chain', 'champagne', 'charge', 'chocolate', 'clean', 'cleaner', 'clerk', 'comfortable', 'concerned', 'control', 'convenient', 'copy', 'correct', 'couch', 'covered', 'day', 'decided', 'deliver', 'description', 'desk', 'diamond', 'did', 'directly', 'does', 'duty', 'email', 'emailed', 'embassy', 'extra', 'eyes', 'false', 'follow', 'free', 'furnished', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'green', 'guess', 'guest', 'half', 'hard', 'heat', 'help', 'helpful', 'high', 'hilton', 'hotel', 'hotels', 'hours', 'housekeeping', 'impressed', 'inch', 'indifferent', 'inside', 'kimpton', 'know', 'late', 'left', 'light', 'like', 'mail', 'make', 'manager', 'member', 'mixed', 'morning', 'needed', 'neighborhood', 'nice', 'night', 'not', 'nothing', 'offer', 'paid', 'phone', 'picky', 'pillows', 'preferred', 'printed', 'prior', 'property', 'provide', 'rates', 'really', 'reservation', 'rise', 'room', 'run', 'said', 'saying', 'screen', 'seattle', 'send', 'sensitive', 'shopping', 'short', 'shot', 'showed', 'sitting', 'sorry', 'special', 'spots', 'staff', 'standard', 'start', 'stay', 'strawberries', 'suite', 'suites', 'suits', 'super', 'sure', 'tape', 'tell', 'the', 'things', 'this', 'told', 'took', 'trip', 'trips', 'unlike', 'view', 'wanted', 'website']
152

------------------------------------------------------

false
kimpton
tape

-------------------------------------------------------

149

-------------------------------------------------------

['amenities', 'arrange', 'arrival', 'asked', 'away', 'bath', 'bathroom', 'bed', 'big', 'blue', 'book', 'bottle', 'box', 'bright', 'broken', 'busy', 'called', 'calls', 'came', 'car', 'champagne', 'change', 'channel', 'check', 'checked', 'checkin', 'choice', 'comfortable', 'comparison', 'concierge', 'cover', 'decided', 'degrees', 'desk', 'did', 'disappointing', 'dock', 'downside', 'driver', 'drop', 'easy', 'experience', 'face', 'facilities', 'far', 'felt', 'filled', 'fish', 'forgot', 'forgotten', 'gesture', 'going', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'happen', 'happy', 'hard', 'hotel', 'housekeeping', 'huge', 'impression', 'ipod', 'jets', 'kept', 'large', 'larger', 'later', 'level', 'light', 'look', 'malfunctioned', 'mediterranean', 'missed', 'morning', 'nap', 'nice', 'night', 'non', 'not', 'open', 'party', 'person', 'picked', 'play', 'positives', 'price', 'provide', 'reasonable', 'relax', 'requests', 'rest', 'room', 'rooms', 'said', 'seattle', 'separate', 'service', 'shower', 'soaking', 'sold', 'sound', 'space', 'special', 'spent', 'square', 'stay', 'suite', 'surprised', 'the', 'tip', 'told', 'touch', 'try', 'tub', 'unit', 'use', 'voucher', 'waiting', 'warm', 'water', 'way', 'weekend', 'work']
124

------------------------------------------------------

dock
malfunctioned

-------------------------------------------------------

122

-------------------------------------------------------

['area', 'bathrobes', 'big', 'chain', 'closed', 'coffee', 'color', 'cosy', 'curtains', 'decor', 'did', 'downtown', 'enjoyed', 'excellent', 'feature', 'feel', 'felt', 'free', 'friendly', 'great', 'hair', 'hotel', 'internet', 'like', 'lobby', 'location', 'look', 'lovely', 'main', 'mix', 'named', 'nice', 'partake', 'personality', 'print', 'pulled', 'rock', 'room', 'service', 'shopping', 'short', 'showed', 'signs', 'sleeping', 'smells', 'staff', 'stars', 'stay', 'striped', 'stroll', 'suite', 'tea', 'thought', 'time', 'touch', 'unique', 'wine', 'wireless', 'wonderful', 'worked']
60

------------------------------------------------------

partake
striped

-------------------------------------------------------

58

-------------------------------------------------------

['accept', 'activities', 'answer', 'apologized', 'area', 'available', 'away', 'awesome', 'barely', 'bathroom', 'besite', 'best', 'better', 'blocks', 'booked', 'bucks', 'building', 'cab', 'called', 'cell', 'charge', 'check', 'christmas', 'city', 'coffee', 'comments', 'company', 'complain', 'deals', 'desk', 'did', 'dog', 'doing', 'doorman', 'dressed', 'driver', 'english', 'evening', 'face', 'fact', 'family', 'floor', 'foyer', 'funny', 'game', 'getting', 'girlfriend', 'going', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'greatest', 'head', 'hear', 'helpful', 'hit', 'homeless', 'hotel', 'hotels', 'house', 'huge', 'issue', 'just', 'keeping', 'knock', 'language', 'large', 'leave', 'lights', 'located', 'making', 'miles', 'mind', 'not', 'offered', 'online', 'package', 'parking', 'pay', 'phone', 'pike', 'place', 'plan', 'police', 'price', 'problem', 'realize', 'recommend', 'return', 'right', 'room', 'said', 'screams', 'second', 'service', 'shops', 'spanish', 'speak', 'spoke', 'stadium', 'staff', 'started', 'stay', 'street', 'taking', 'talking', 'tasting', 'taxi', 'tell', 'thing', 'time', 'told', 'took', 'travel', 'tub', 'turn', 'view', 'voucher', 'vouchers', 'walk', 'walked', 'want', 'waterfront', 'way', 'website', 'websites', 'went', 'wine', 'wonderful', 'worked']
130

------------------------------------------------------

besite
screams

-------------------------------------------------------

128

-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please share the `word_ratings_merged` df

Comment: I added the first five entries of the dataframe.
Just to note, it does cut the word list short.
Also, this is fresh, before I ran the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same piece of code as yours

```
import pandas as pd

word_ratings_merged = pd.DataFrame([{"Rating": 4, "unique_words": [1, 2, 3]}, {"Rating": 2, "unique_words": [4, 5, 6]}])

word_score_series_copy = {6: "abc", 2: "gef"}

sample_data = word_ratings_merged

# Create a copy
data_c = sample_data.copy()

for w_list in data_c.unique_words:
    word_list = w_list
    print ("Processing :{}".format(word_list))
    print ("Length of words list before: {}".format(len(word_list)))
    for word in word_list:
        if word in word_score_series_copy.keys():
            pass
        else:
            word_list.remove(word)
            print ("Removed element {}".format(word))
    print ("Length of words list after : {}".format(len(word_list)))
```

Output:

```
Processing :[1, 2, 3]
Length of words list before: 3
Removed element 1
Removed element 3
Length of words list after 1
Processing :[4, 5, 6]
Length of words list before: 3
Removed element 4
Length of words list after 2
```

In my case, there is no shortening of the list.

PS: - I used a dict here because I need to use .keys()

`word_score_series_copy = {6: "abc", 2: "gef"}`

Comment: I updated the original question with my output, when I run the loop the first time compared to the second run.